# Dart: Comparing two objects of any type to check if they are equal

Tags: flutter, dart

I use the following code to compare two `Person` object using the overridden `==` operator:

```
class Person {
  String ssn;
  String name;

  Person(this.ssn, this.name);

  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    return identical(this, other) ||
      other is Person && 
      ssn == other.ssn &&
      name == other.name;
  }
  
  @override int get hashCode => (ssn + name).hashCode;
}

main() {
  var bob =  Person('111', 'Bob');
  var robert =  Person('123', 'Robert');

  print(bob == robert); // false
}
```

However, as this code works perfectly with `Person` objects, is there a way to write one `==` operator function that works for any two types to compare them to check if they are equal or not ?

Comment: Have u tried using `identical()` from `dart:core` ? https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.6.1/dart-core/identical.html

Comment: it's used in the code snippet above

Comment: Oh didnt notice. But i think thats how you compare 2 objects. Someone else can give better solution.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for.  Are you asking how to make `Person.operator ==` work if the `other` object isn't a `Person`?  Or are you asking how to avoid implementing an `operator ==`  override for every class?

Comment: avoid implementing an operator == override for every class

Comment: You can try [`package:equatable`](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) to make it slightly less tedious, but otherwise there's no automatic way without code generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is how not to write `equals` and `hashCode` implementation for all your classes then the answer would be there is no way right now. But you can simplify this process with packages. For example, you can use [Equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) package then your class would look like this:

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Person extends Equatable {
  String ssn;
  String name;

  Person(this.ssn, this.name);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [name, ssn];
}
```

Comment: yes this is what I meant, thank you. I just thought that there is some like Reflection in dart like in Swift